# Change image in aem which is in css file without manually changing the path in css file manually

Tags: css, aem

I need a reference to my dam image [/content/dam/myproject/image_i_need] which is there in css file under client libs. How to change the image path by authoring (without manually changing the path in css file). may be with dialog edit is possible.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution that might work:

Make a component that takes an image input reference from DAM by the authors. Generate an inline CSS with the relevant style and a reference to the user selected image. This could be something like below (consider image background example):

```
.inline-user-class {
   background-image: url("/content/dam/myproject/image_i_need");
}
```

You can then use this inline class with your element as:

```
<div class='inline-user-class'>
</div>
```

There are pros and cons of doing this which are associated with inline CSS but given that your users want to treat CSS as content then this is the simplest option.

> This pattern is highly discouraged in AEM (or any other CMS) for one simple reason:
>
> **CSS is not content**

A CMS is primarily designed for content management so unless your authors want to take ownership of the CSS, they shouldn't be treating images referenced from CSS as a content.

Inversely, a CSS should never reference an Asset (image, video, etc.) that can be modified by the authors. In AEM, this means /content/dam should not be referenced in CSS if authors can modify it.

Hope this helps.